# Is Earth Jambudvipa or Bhu-mandala?

Tags: puranas, geography

Is Earth Jambudvipa or Bhu-mandala?

There are seven dvipas in BhUloka. One of the dvipas  is Jambudvipa. Jambudvipa has 9 varshas. One of the varshas in Jambudvipa is Bharatavarsha:

> [Text 5:](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/5/16/5/) Bhū-maṇḍala resembles a lotus flower, and its seven
> islands resemble the whorl of that flower. The length and breadth of
> the island known as Jambūdvīpa, which is situated in the middle of the
> whorl, is one million yojanas. Jambūdvīpa is round like the leaf of a
> lotus flower.
>
> Text 6: In Jambūdvīpa there are nine varshas, each with a length of
> 9,000 yojanas. There are eight mountains that mark the boundaries of
> these divisions and separate them nicely.

Bharata Varsha is clearly India from this verse:

> [5.16.9](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/5/16/9/) - Similarly, south of Ilāvṛta-varṣa and extending from east to west are three great mountains named (from north to south) Niṣadha, Hemakūṭa and Himālaya. Each of them is 10,000 yojanas high. They mark the boundaries of the three varṣas named Hari-varṣa, Kimpuruṣa-varṣa and Bhārata-varṣa [India].

So is Jambudvipa Earth? Or is this geography purely mythological, like Atlantis?

Comment: I think jambudvipa is Asia. krouncha is america. we use that in sankalpam. also i think pangea used to be the original combined landmass until it was divided by an ancient king (probably Manu) for his 7 sons.

Comment: @mar America can't be Krauncha. Krauncha is said to be surrounded by an ocean of milk: Bhagavatam 5.20.18 - "Krauñcadvīpa is surrounded by an ocean of milk". America is surrounded by an ocean of salt water ocean. Therefore, America can't be Krauncha, but only part of Jambudvipa (since only Jambu is surrounded by salt water ocean), which is why I think the whole Earth is Jambudvipa since the whole earth is only surrounded/encompassed by salt water ocean.

Comment: Hearing that Krauñca is America is kinda a joke